# Can I safely memmove around a boost variant?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I have a class wrapping a boost variant that only contains memmovable types (QList, QString, int etc).

May I declare that wrapper class memmovable to Qt containers?

Answer (score 2):

A `boost::variant` contains only an integral index and an `aligned_storage`, which is guaranteed by the standard to be a POD. It has no virtual members, but has user-defined constructors and a destructor. As a consequence, `boost::variant` is not a POD and trying to memmove it is UB (well, I think it is UB, I don't find a definitive reference in the standard).

However, the same can be said for `QList`, `QString`, etc. [Apparently](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq19-containers.html), Qt assumes that some non-POD types can be safely memmoved, and makes a distinction between POD (so-called "primitive types") and "movable types".

Consequently, if you think it is safe to memmove a `QList`, you can consider it safe to memmove a `boost::variant` containing memmovable types.

Answer (score 1):

You probably know that memmoving non-POD types is technically undefined behaviour. That aside, variant doesn't contain anything that would be problematic if memmoved. Since you mention QList and QString as being memmovable, and I have difficulty believing that they are PODs (although I haven't seen them), boost::variant is no worse.